# Enumerate with different first line?

Tags: formatting, lists, enumerate

I want to do an enumeration, but the first line should be bolded, see e.g. this picture:

[image]

What is blue I want to have in bold. In addition, I don't know how to generate a new line for the other text in the enumerate environment, should I just use `\\` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\textbf{...}` around text that you want to embolden and `\\` to break a line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[\bfseries1.]
\item \textbf{Specify a mean equation for the returns}\\
by testing for serial dependence of $r_t$ an, if necessary, building an ARMA model
\item \textbf{Test for ARCH Effects}\\
using the residuals of the mean equation
\item \textbf{Specify a volatility model} (if necessary)
\item \textbf{Estimate the complete model}\\
via joint estimation of mean an volatility parameters 
\item \textbf{Check the fitted model}\\
and refine if necessary.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample code output]

Answer (score 4):

For more automation, you may want to define a new command `\bitem`, as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\bitem[1]{\item{\bfseries #1}\\}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \bitem {Specify a mean equation for the returns}
        by testing for serial dependence of $r_t$ an, if necessary, building an ARMA model
    \bitem {Test for ARCH Effects} using the residuals of the mean equation
    \bitem {Specify a volatility model} (if necessary)
    \bitem {Estimate the complete model}
        via joint estimation of mean an volatility parameters
    \bitem {Check the fitted model} and refine if necessary.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd use only one argument: `\bitem{bold text} Whatever follows`

Comment: You're right yet again :)